# How many tablets can bigtable store?

Tags: java, database, hbase, bigtable

From the paper of bigtable. [bigtable](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1365816)
I read this:

> Each METADATA row stores approximately 1KB of data in memory.  With a
>   modest limit of 128 MB METADATA tablets, our three-level location
>   scheme is sufficient to address 2^34 tablets.

I am confusing because 2^10 * 2^7 = 2^17

How could it store 2^34 tablets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Figure 4: Tablet location hierarchy

The root tablet contains the location of all tablets in a special METADATA table.
Each METADATA tablet contains the location of a set of user tablets.

2^17 (METADATA tablet) * 2^17 (user tablets) = 2^34